# Python: using RuntimeWarning to adapt my code to unexpected issues

Tags: python, statsmodels

Dears,

I am using Python 3 for performing a large number of regression models on data. I am adding different parameters to the model in loops to test if the model is better than other combinations of parameters. I use statsmodel & logit.fit()

I face the problem that for some of the models, there is convergence but the hessian matrix can't be inverted, preventing calculations of some statistics -> pvalues.

The log contains the following: RuntimeWarning: Inverting hessian failed, no bse or cov_params available
  warn(warndoc, RuntimeWarning)

My problem is the following: whatever the model I capture the same set of statistics but when this problem occurs it crashes all my algorithm and my program stops.

Do you know how I could capture this runtimewarning info so that I can adapt my set of statistics to only those available and avoid then crashing of the program?

Comment: You could open an issue on statsmodels github. There will be some attribute that can be checked (maybe `results.normalized_cov_params is None`), but I think there is no stable API for this, that means it might have to change in the next statsmodels version.

Comment: @user333700 Thanks for your insight. Checking that attribute allowed me to avoid trying retrieving pvalues when no hessian matrix could be inverted. To be complete, I used the following conditions for pvalue generation: np.isnan(result.normalized_cov_params.iloc[0][0])==False with a previous importation of numpy: import numpy as np.